# Too many rows from a Join

Tags: sql, join, case, where-clause

I am trying to join two tables where I wish the result to be just two extra columns and no extra rows in the result table.

I am joining with the purpose to get an attribute when the attribute value is True and when the attribute name is either three different types.

When I join the tables, I of course get one extra row per existing attribute name, but I don't know how to constrain this to not happen.

That is, from below code I wish to only get a column with ForwardCurveName and Attribute_Name for each existing row (Trade_Id).
The Case code is to give me the wanted output when the other table's Attribute_Value is True and only for three different kind of _Names.

In the Attribute table, there is 15 attributes, and there can be multiple "True" attributes.

This is my first question here, so I hope I made it understandable! Thanks,

Some sample data:

- In Attribute-table
  The column Entity_Key is the same as Trade_Id and appears 15 times with its 15 different attribute value
  The column Attribute_Value consist of False, True, ids, numbers, names because it is a mix of many different values

The column `Attribute_Name` is text names of different values, and I am only interesting in those names "NCG", "GPN", "TTF".

(Not sure how to displace data without screenshot which is not really allowed in these posts as I read it)

| Row | Entity_Id | Attribute_Value | Attribute_Name | Data_Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NE00020216 | True | NCG | Boolean |
| 2 | NE00020216 | False | TTF | Boolean |
| 3 | NE00020216 | False | GPN | Boolean |
| 4 | NE00020216 | 5 | Othername | Number |
| 5 | .... |  |  |  |
| 6 | .... |  |  |  |

In the `Trades` table:

| Trade_Id | Day | Volumes... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NE00020216 | Day 1 | 20 |
| NE00020216 | Day 2 | 10 |
| NE00020216 | Day 3 | 100 |
| NE00020216 | Day 4 | 50 |

In the Result-table:
I want to get row 1 from the Attribute-table into the Trades-table, because row 1 is "True" and named "NCG". And I want it to be in the existing rows, and not adding extra rows for each Day as my current code does.

| Trade_Id | Day | Volumes... | ForwardCurveName | Attribute_Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NE00020216 | Day 1 | 20 | NCG Heren | NCG |
| NE00020216 | Day 2 | 10 | NCG Heren | NCG |
| NE00020216 | Day 3 | 100 | NCG Heren | NCG |
| NE00020216 | Day 4 | 50 | NCG Heren | NCG |

```
select 

t.Trade_Id
,TP.Start_Trade as Day
,tp.volume * 12.157/1000 as Contracted_Volume -- Due to the Start_Trade code, this volume is only for the future periods, and not the total for each trade
,tp.volume * 12.157/1000/24 as MwH
,t.Counterparty_name
,t.Trade_Type
,t.Product_Type_Name
,month(TP.Start_Trade) as Month
,year(TP.Start_Trade) as Year
,case
   when (a.Attribute_Value = 'true' and a.attribute_name = 'NCG') then 'NCG Heren'
   when (a.Attribute_Value = 'true' and a.attribute_name = 'TTF') then 'TTF Heren'
   when (a.Attribute_Value = 'true' and a.attribute_name = 'GPN') then 'GPN Heren'
   else 'Mistake'
end as ForwardCurveName
, a.Attribute_Name

from entrader.Trades_vw T
--Left join [Reporting].[Trade_Hubs_vw] TH on t.Trade_Id = Th.Trade_Id
left JOIN Entrader.Trade_Period_vw AS TP ON T.Trade_Id = TP.Trade_Id
left join core.Attribute_Values_vw as A on t.Trade_Id = a.Entity_Key
```

Comment: Answer depends on which row you want to keep and which to avoid. Please clarify this detail.

Comment: You can add "I am getting this: ..." and "I would like to get this: ..."

Comment: Thanks, updated with your input.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to S/O.  You were probably very close.  If your attribute table has multiple rows, that is why you would get multiple returned.  If, however, your attribute table has only one where the attribute_value = 'true', I have shifted that out of the case/when and moved it to the join so it will only ever consider returning the "true" attribute.

Now, if you have the possibility of multiple attributes being true, you will still end up with multiple rows returned.  Editing your existing post and showing some sample data now and the future will help others help you better too.

```
select 
        t.Trade_Id,
        TP.Start_Trade as Day,
        -- Due to the Start_Trade code, this volume is only for the future periods, and not the total for each trade
        tp.volume * 12.157 / 1000 Contracted_Volume,
        tp.volume * 12.157 / 1000 / 24 MwH,
        t.Counterparty_name,
        t.Trade_Type,
        t.Product_Type_Name,
        month(TP.Start_Trade) as Month,
        year(TP.Start_Trade) as Year,
        case when a.attribute_name = 'NCG' then 'NCG Heren'
            when a.attribute_name = 'TTF' then 'TTF Heren'
            when a.attribute_name = 'GPN' then 'GPN Heren'
            else 'Mistake' end ForwardCurveName, 
        a.Attribute_Name
    from 
        entrader.Trades_vw T
        --Left join [Reporting].[Trade_Hubs_vw] TH on t.Trade_Id = Th.Trade_Id
        left JOIN Entrader.Trade_Period_vw TP 
            ON T.Trade_Id = TP.Trade_Id
        left join core.Attribute_Values_vw A 
            on t.Trade_Id = a.Entity_Key
            AND a.Attribute_Value = 'true'
```

Comment: HI DRapp, Thanks for reply, and you are right, that there can be multiple values set as True in the Attribute table. So your fine code is unfortunately not solving my problem though it got closer! I tried to add some sample data, but unsure how to present it.